# return 2 values from a function for two different columns with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have applied a function to a column of my dataframe, this column contains the date with year, month, day and hour, minute, second and what i would like to do is to separate year, month, day and put it in a column and hour, minute, second put it in another column at the same time, my code looks like this

```
def change_format(day):
  if day != 'nan':  
    format_1 = datetime.strptime(day, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z  %Y")

    new_day = format_1.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    new_time = format_1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')                               
  return new_day,new_time
concatenar['pubDate']=concatenar['pubDate'].apply(change_format)
```

so far in my column it does not return any values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your tuple output to list using `.tolist()` and then use `pd.DataFrame()` to construct the dataframe with the 2 required columns, as follows:

```
concatenar[["pubDate_date","pubDate_time"]] = pd.DataFrame(concatenar["pubDate"].apply(change_format).tolist(), index=concatenar.index)
```

Using `pd.DataFrame()` is much faster than `pd.Series()`.  You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64563986/15070697) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46232267/15070697) of some other posts for the speed comparison between using `pd.DataFrame()` and `pd.Series()` for building new columns.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code it's not clear where you want the second column to go. Your current apply function should be returning a column where each entry is a tuple. To unpack it into two columns you have to specify which two columns to put the output and can use apply() again with pd.Series().

```
concatenar[ ["pubDate_day","pubDate_time"] ] = concatenar["pubDate"].apply(change_format).apply(pd.Series)
```

You can read more about unpacking columns of tuples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799300/how-to-unpack-a-series-of-tuples-in-pandas).