# How to form tuple column from two columns in Pandas of only non empty values

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

This is an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031056/how-to-form-tuple-column-from-two-columns-in-pandas/16068497#16068497)

using

```
 df['new_col'] = zip(df.lat, df.long)
```

to combine multiple columns into tuple

how to drop (or not add) empty elements (column) that is tuple should contain only non-empty values

just to give an example:

```
instead of ('a','') or ('a',)
display     ('a')
```

also, is there a way to convert the tuple to a set

Comment: shouldn't `df1 = df.dropna(subset=['lat','long']) df['new_col'] = zip(df1['lat'], df1['long'])` work? also what are you intending to display where 1 or both cols are null?

Comment: just empty tuple, I just used the example from linked thread, I am working on different applicaition

Comment: That seems to make a little sense: with your example, the output type is either a tuple or a single element, depending on the row. You can't have two output types together for a column.

Comment: Tuple to set: `set(mytuple)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful comments guys, Here's something that worked for me:

```
import copy
def remove_empty(x):
    for c in copy.copy(x): 
        if not c: 
            x.discard(c)
    return x

df['new_col'] = zip(df.lat, df.long)
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].apply(set)
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].apply(remove_empty)
```