# Combine multiple columns into 1 column [python,pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with 2 columns: 
`{'A':[1, 2, 3],'B':[4, 5, 6]}`

I want to create a new column where:
`{'C':[1 4,2 5,3 6]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind zip object, then you can use`df['C'] = zip(df.A,df.B)`.
If you like tuple then you can cast zip object with `list()`. Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031056/how-to-form-tuple-column-from-two-columns-in-pandas). It's pretty handy to use zip in this kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3],'B':[4, 5, 6]})
```

#### Solution

Keep in mind, per your expected output, `[1 4,2 5,3 6]` isn't a thing.  I'm interpreting you to mean either `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]` or `["1 4", "2 5", "3 6"]`

#### First assumption

```
df.apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values), axis=1)

0    (1, 4)
1    (2, 5)
2    (3, 6)
dtype: object
```

#### Second assumption

```
df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)

0    1 4
1    2 5
2    3 6
dtype: object
```

Comment: Great answer! However using `apply` would take a long time for large files. But it leads to desired results.