# Join(Combine) two series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to join/combine two columns in a data frame.

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3], 'B' : [4, 5, 6]})
```

**Desired Output**

```
14
25
36
```

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425628/combine-multiple-columns-into-1-column-python-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply` with `join`

```
dat.astype(str).apply(''.join,1)
Out[210]: 
0    14
1    25
2    36
dtype: object
```

Or (PS not always work)

```
dat.A*10+dat.B
Out[211]: 
0    14
1    25
2    36
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you define the columns in the first solution?

Comment: @Vedda using `dat.astype(str).apply(''.join,1).to_frame('Yourname')` or you need ? 

dat[['A','B']].astype(str).apply(''.join,1)