# using query in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Assume I have the following table:
[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPoVU.jpg)

I add a column called "status" which is the pairs (gender, senior_management), which is basically the pairs: [ (Female, True), (Male, True), (Male, False), ...] and so on.
suppose I am looking for certain conditions, so I defined the list:

```
conditions = [(Female, True), (Male, False)]
```

my goal is now to use query to make a new data frame that has only values that have condition. I currently have (note that MyDataframe is the old one and I'm trying to save it as a new one while keeping the old one):

```
NewDataFrame = MyDataFrame.query('status in @conditions')
NewDataframe.head()
```

this only results in the column names of the data frame:
[Flawed_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Uqc.png)
What is happening here? and how do I fix it?

Comment: With a dummy dataframe, it works for me. How do you create the 'status' column? it could be as well, that maybe True and False were strings.

Comment: interesting! so this same code works for you? i create my new column by doing: 

`MyDataFrame['status'] = MyDataFrame.apply(lambda row: "({},{})".format(row['Gender'],row['Senior Management']), axis=1)`
I checked and the column was created successfully. Any ideas why this is an issue?


NOTEWORTHY: When I tried ti print the dataframe using:
`print(NewDataFrame)`
the output is: Empty DataFrame (Followed by the list of column names)

Comment: That's the reason why it wasn't working. See my answer. @Beginner101

Comment: Also, if you find it helpful, consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)! @Beginner101

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the answer. Could you be more Specific? I don't see how the type would matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `status` column it's of type string, because when you use format you cast the expression to a string, so it will not match never with the `conditions` list of tuples, so you can try to define the `conditions` list as strings:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['Male','Female','Male','Female'],'Senior':[True,True,False,False]})
df['status']=df.apply(lambda row: "({},{})".format(row['gender'],row['Senior']), axis=1)
df
#   gender  Senior          status
#0    Male    True     (Male,True)
#1  Female    True   (Female,True)
#2    Male   False    (Male,False)
#3  Female   False  (Female,False)
conditions = ['(Female,True)', '(Male,False)']

df.query('status in @conditions')
```

Output:

```
   gender  Senior         status
1  Female    True  (Female,True)
2    Male   False   (Male,False)
```

---

If you want to have as a tuple instead of a string, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068497/13676202) to get the tuples, and then make the query

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['Male','Female','Male','Female'],'Senior':[True,True,False,False]}) 

df['status']=list(zip(df.gender, df.Senior))

conditions = [('Female',True), ('Male',False)]
df.query('status in @conditions')
```

Comment: I used strings to define conditions and it worked! Thank you so much for the help! :)