# Series of Dates to Series of Date Intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a series of Dates to a series of Date Intervals but cannot figure out how to do it in one beautiful query. I would like it to operate in the same way that the .diff() method operates. See the image of the behavior I am expecting.

[image]

I have nearly extracted the information I am looking for with this like code:

```
dates = {}
for key,item in app.sort_values('Date').groupby('UniqueId'):
    x = list(item.Date)
    date_range = []
    for k in range(0,len(x)-1):
        date_range.append([x[k],x[k+1]])
        
    dates.update({key:date_range})
```

Any Direction Helps. Thanks!

Comment: `df['Intervals'] = list(zip(df['Dates'].shift(-1), df['Dates']))` (convert two columns to a tuple https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068497/5125264 plus the lag operator to shift the series by one https://stackoverflow.com/a/66258734/5125264)

Comment: Fantastic this works as intended. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using pandas shift

```
# Create dataframe
dates=['12/14/20 18:28','12/16/20 18:28','12/19/20 18:36','5/18/21 23:48']
cols=['dates']
df=pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=cols)

df['intervals'] = df['dates'].shift(1)+','+df['dates']
```

Comment: This worked. Nice solution thank you! I was not aware of the shift function, but now I am adding it to the tool box.