# Is there a way to group id's with corresponding alternate id in python

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

Currently, I am working on grouping transactions based on a product ID. The problem is that a product can contain various alternate IDs that can be located in two columns. For example, a product can look like this in the dataset;

| requested ID | Item ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123t-34 | 4s4532t |
| :------------ | -------: |
| 4s4532t. | 123t-34 |
| :------------ | -------: |
| 123t-34. | 4s4532t |

This is an example of a much bigger dataset. Any input on how I could group  them to look something similar to this;

| Id. | Alternate Ids |
| --- | --- |
| 123t-34 | (4s4532t,123t-34) |

This is my attempt to solve the problem.
`data_dict = data.groupby('requested_id')['Item ID'].agg('unique')`

But this only solved half of the grouping based on one column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.itertuples`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031056/how-to-form-tuple-column-from-two-columns-in-pandas) to build a tuple from two or more columns.

Try this :

```
(
    data.assign(AlternateIDs= list(df[df.columns[::-1]].itertuples(index=False, name=None)))
        .rename(columns={'requested ID': 'Id.'})
        .drop(columns='Item ID')
)
```

##### # Output :

```
        Id.         AlternateIDs
0   123t-34   (4s4532t, 123t-34)
1  4s4532t.  (123t-34, 4s4532t.)
2  123t-34.  (4s4532t, 123t-34.)
```